# Install audio drive codec CX2072X in to my ubuntu

Tags: linux, audio, driver, codec

I have installed the latest version of ubuntu (`Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - kernel 4.15.0-43-generi`c) on my pc `Cherry Trail - Intel Atomx5 Z8350`.
But the sound card is not recognized.

After reading some forums it seems that sound card driver is not present on my setup.

Under windows the sound card works with Intel SST Audio Device drivers while it should match the `CX2072X drive-codec` for linux.

I have seen the link which shows the codec driver compilation on 4.18 kernel version.
https://github.com/conexant/codec_drivers/commit/4d9cfc5188c6c2709b1d7533a363ff485294c1e3

But I do not know how to install them in my ubuntu and also do I need to install the kernel version 4.18 before these for the compatibility issue.

Sorry I am not much familiar with Linux so any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly last year cx2072x driver upstreaming was in progress. Check this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001071/how-to-build-the-driver-for-cx2072x-codec for building the  codec driver

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I already tried you link, but I have no sound in HDMI output.
what I need.
looking at the cx2072x.c and cx2072.h files of my link, look more recent. I wanted to try them to figure out if I solve for hdmi audio output.
There is no way to try them?

Comment: audio works with ubuntu 18.10 and pavucontrol.